# Dynamic Buttons in with ListView using ObervableCollection in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, button, dynamic

I want to show Buttons depending on availible options but im getting some troubles implementing it.

Would be nice if someone could take a look at my code.

The Collection is good, but there are no buttons showing.

I already tried the following:

```cs
public ObservableCollection<Button> shownButtons { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Button>();

private void ActionSelector(){
Button button;
            foreach (var serviceAction in basedata)
            {
                switch (serviceAction.ChangeType)
                {
                    case ServiceTodoChangeType.Accept:
                        button = new Button()
                        {
                            //Command = AcceptServiceCommand,
                            Text = Translations.Accept
                        };
                        shownButtons.Add(button);
                        break;
                    case ServiceTodoChangeType.ServicePause:
                        button = new Button()
                        {
                            Command = BreakCommand,
                            Text = Translations.ServicePause
                        };
                        shownButtons.Add(button);
                        break;
}
}
}
```

The XAML:

```xml
<ListView ItemsSource="shownButtons">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <Button 
                                     Text="{Binding Text}" 
                                     Command="{Binding Command}">
                                    </Button>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
```

Comment: what is the type of shownButtons?

Comment: public ObservableCollection<Button> shownButtons { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Button>();
@Jason

Comment: The ListView is responsible for creating the UI elements in the template.  You would typically create your own model class and use an ObservableCollection<MyClass> for the ItemsSource.  Actually creating the buttons yourself isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the error...

I forgot to bind the Source.

Fix:

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding shownButtons}">
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ViewCell>
                                        <Button 
                                         Text="{Binding Text}" 
                                         Command="{Binding Command}">
                                        </Button>
                                    </ViewCell>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
```